# Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, heroku

while I was launching my ML model using Heroku the build logs show that:

```bash
Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/C:/Windows/TEMP/abs_e9b7158a-aa56-4a5b-87b6-c00d295b01fanefpc8_o/croots/recipe/certifi_1655968940823/work/certifi'
```

Please help to fix this.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same error here. And I found there is the path in my `requirements.txt` **line2**. After I remove the path everythins work, maybe you can check your requirements.txt, HTH

[image]

Comment: Like @swchen my requirements file contained paths to files for certain packages. In my case, multiple packages had file paths. Deleting the paths (leaving just the name of the package to install) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error in a local computer with **Windows 10**.

I uninstalled certifi:

```bash
pip uninstall certifi
```

and then installed it again:

```bash
pip install certifi
```

And it works.

I have noticed a problem doing the `requirements` file in a completely new project.

Answer (score 0):

If the error originates from Heroku logs it is most likely that you hard coded a path to the directory in your code( Because heroku does not have a directory as `/C:/Windows/TEMP` in deployment).

Otherwise please share the code so we can help trace where the error originates :)

Comment: https://github.com/AnkitAnuragi/Aqideployment

Comment: github link of the code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).