# OSError [Errno 2] No such file or directory while installing Jupyter Notebook in Python 3.11 on Windows 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to install Jupyter Notebook on my Windows 11 machine using Python 3.11.4, but I encounter an OSError with the message:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

I have already tried different installation commands, including `pip install notebook`, `pip install notebook --user`, and `python -m pip install jupyter`, but none of them resolved the issue.

Error details:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\jedi\third_party\typeshed\third_party\2and3\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\ssl_match_hostname\_implementation.pyi'

I have also referred to the following Stack Overflow links, but the solutions provided did not help me resolve the issue:

1. [Python: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980952/python-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or)
2. [Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/C:/Windows/TEMP/abs_e9b7158a-aa56-4a5b-87b6-c00d295b01fanefpc8_o/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72831972/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-director)

How to resolve this OSError and successfully install Jupyter Notebook on Python 3.11 running on Windows 11?

I have verified that my pip version is 23.2.1 and tried to install Jupyter Notebook using both system-wide and user-specific installation options, but the error persists.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly installing urllib3 with pip first and then installing Jedi and then finally trying to install notebook? Yea totally should work automatically but it's windows...

Comment: Tried that. Didn't help. For `pip install urllib3` `Requirement already satisfied`. And for `pip install Jedi`, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you using virtual environements? If not I would start there, and you don't need to use conda just `python -m venv <path to your new env>`. Don't forget to activate the environment no matter which venv route you go. Then try a fresh install of Jedi + jupyter. If all else failes, if you have access, the Win 11 Ubuntu WSL is pretty stable and you can connect IDE's like VS Code to dev in.